# Export all data from wpf DataGrid to a List<int>

Tags: c#, list, wpfdatagrid

i'm from Russia! I'm sorry for my english! How do I put the all contents from wpf DataGrid in collection  List ?
These data in a DataGrid from an array of int [,] m_intArray = new int [5, 5] and additionally attached column DataGridComboBoxColumn

```
    private int[,] m_intArray = new int[5, 5];
    private DataGridComboBoxColumn box = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
    private List<Vary> col1 = new List<Vary>();

    public class Vary
    {
        public int vy { get; set; }

    }

    private void Create()
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                m_intArray[i, j] = (i * 10 + j);
            }
        }

         col1.Add(new Vary { vy = 1 });
         col1.Add(new Vary { vy = 2 });

    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Create();
        c_dataGrid.ItemsSource = BindingHelper.GetBindable2DArray<int>(m_intArray);
        box.Header = "Y";
        box.ItemsSource = col1;
        box.DisplayMemberPath = "vy";
        box.SelectedItemBinding = new Binding("vy");
        c_dataGrid.Columns.Add(box);
        c_dataGrid.Items.Refresh();

    }
```

After selecting the values ​​in the ComboBox and press the button "Generate" to put all the values ​​in the collection List  for further work with these values ​​...
How do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating a property or a field in your view's code behind storing your collection of integers. If you have it, you can bind it to your datagrid's data source and then reuse it (for example to convert it to a generic list of integers).

Please also consider using some design pattern (like MVVM), because you definitely will have lots of problems using just code behind.

Comment: You can give a small example, please!